Slack files.completeUploadExternal no uploading files to the Slack
Since the slack file.upload is going to be depreciated, I was going to make new the methods work.
The first one works as:
curl -s -F files=@test.txt -F filename=test.txt -F token=xoxp-token -F length=50123 https://slack.com/api/files.getUploadURLExternal

and returns
{"ok":true,"upload_url":"https:\/\/files.slack.com\/upload\/v1\/CwABAAAAXAoAAVnX....","file_id":"F07XXQ9XXXX"}

The second request is:
curl -X POST \  -H "Authorization: Bearer xoxp-token" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "files": [{"id":"F07XXXXXX", "title":"Slack API updates Testing"}],
        "channel_id": "C06EXXXXX"
      }' \
  https://slack.com/api/files.completeUploadExternal

With the second request, I get 200 OK responses.
{"ok":true,"files":[{"id":"XXXXXXX","created":XXXXXXXX,"timestamp":XXXXXXXX,"name":"test.txt","title":"Slack API updates Testing","mimetype":"","filetype":"","pretty_type":"","user":"XXXXXXXXX","user_team":"XXXXXXXXX","editable":false,"size":50123,"mode":"hosted","is_external":false,"external_type":"","is_public":false,"public_url_shared":false,"display_as_bot":false,"username":"","url_private":"https:\/\/files.slack.com\/files-pri\/XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX\/test.txt","url_private_download":"https:\/\/files.slack.com\/files-pri\/XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX\/download\/test.txt","media_display_type":"unknown","permalink":"https:\/\/XXXXXXXX.slack.com\/files\/XXXXXXXXX\/XXXXXXX\/test.txt","permalink_public":"https:\/\/slack-files.com\/XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX","comments_count":0,"is_starred":false,"shares":{},"channels":[],"groups":[],"ims":[],"has_more_shares":false,"has_rich_preview":false,"file_access":"visible"}],"warning":"missing_charset","response_metadata":{"warnings":["missing_charset"]}}

Questions and problems:
1- How do I determine the length= in the first request (files.getUploadURLExternal
)
2- Even though I have provided the channel_id the file is still not getting uploaded on the Slack channel.
Documentation:
https://api.slack.com/methods/files.completeUploadExternal
https://api.slack.com/methods/files.getUploadURLExternal

You skipped a step.  You have to send a POST to the URL that is returned to you on the first step.  In that post you are also doing the file upload.
2nd step should be:
curl -F  filename="@$filename" -H "Authorization: Bearer $SLACK_KEY" -v POST $upload_url
then your 2nd step should be the 3rd step.
As far as getting the byte size stat --printf="%s" file if you are using bash

how do you know that it receives an 'filename' args? and what is the $ mean before filename? what if the filename is undersome path?
I tried the above, with csv file, changing the content type in header to be text/csv but still didnt work

This is the complete bash script to upload any file using the slack API. Stage 4 is optional, only for personal token.
#!/bin/bash

export FILE_PATH="/folder/your.file"
export CHANNEL_ID="C_some_number"
export TOKEN="your_token"
FILENAME=$(basename "$FILE_PATH")

# Get the file size using macOS compatible stat command. use stat -c%s "$FILE_PATH" otherwise
FILE_SIZE=$(stat -f%z "$FILE_PATH")

# Stage 1: Get an upload URL
UPLOAD_URL_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -F files=@"$FILENAME" -F filename="$FILENAME" -F token=$TOKEN -F length=$FILE_SIZE https://slack.com/api/files.getUploadURLExternal)

UPLOAD_URL=$(echo "$UPLOAD_URL_RESPONSE" | jq -r '.upload_url')
FILE_ID=$(echo "$UPLOAD_URL_RESPONSE" | jq -r '.file_id')

if [ "$UPLOAD_URL" == "null" ]; then
  echo "Error getting upload URL: $UPLOAD_URL_RESPONSE"
  exit 1
fi

# Stage 2: Upload the file to the provided URL
UPLOAD_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST \
  -T "$FILE_PATH" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
  "$UPLOAD_URL")

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Error uploading file: $UPLOAD_RESPONSE"
  exit 1
fi

# Stage 3: Complete the upload, and post the message and the file
COMPLETE_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" \
  -d '{
        "files": [
          {
            "id": "'"$FILE_ID"'"
          }
        ],
        "channel_id": "'"$CHANNEL_ID"'",
        "initial_comment": "Hello file 001"
      }' \
  https://slack.com/api/files.completeUploadExternal)

if [ "$(echo "$COMPLETE_RESPONSE" | jq -r '.ok')" != "true" ]; then
  echo "Error completing upload: $COMPLETE_RESPONSE"
  exit 1
fi

# OPTIONAL Stage 4: Share the uploaded file in a channel, only if it was not performed in the previous stage
SHARE_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" \
  -d '{
        "channel": "'"$CHANNEL_ID"'",
        "file": "'"$FILE_ID"'",
        "initial_comment": "Hello file 002"
      }' \
  https://slack.com/api/files.sharedPublicURL)

if [ "$(echo "$SHARE_RESPONSE" | jq -r '.ok')" != "true" ]; then
  echo "Error sharing file: $SHARE_RESPONSE"
  exit 1
fi

echo "File successfully uploaded. Is not then check your token scopes"


Im doing the same with my bot but in the step 2 when you have to upload the file, im getting an error "internal error: put".
upload_file = HTTP::Client.post(upload_url, headers, body: file_basename) //tried using file_basename and file_path
This is the answer to upload_file
#<HTTP::Client::Response:0x7f923f16caf0 @version="HTTP/1.1", @status=INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, @status_message="Internal Server Error", @headers=HTTP::Headers{"Content-Type" => "text/plain", "Content-Length" => "19", "Connection" => "close", "x-backend" => "miata-prod-gru-v2-5bcfb8465b-pt2fj", "date" => "Wed, 29 May 2024 19:06:28 GMT", "x-envoy-upstream-service-time" => "2", "x-edge-backend" => "miata", "x-slack-edge-shared-secret-outcome" => "shared-secret", "server" => "envoy", "via" => "envoy-edge-gru-cseuczvq, 1.1 5ea4a2b9e3595a42471d782e7c7054d0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)", "X-Cache" => "Error from cloudfront", "X-Amz-Cf-Pop" => "EZE50-P1", "X-Amz-Cf-Id" => "LfAqYrT_5Pc-XdooQfTjR9U2cH4uxabEx-5Yki8r5qVKPSRVY-2UQw==", "Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy" => "cross-origin"}, @body_io=nil, @cookies=nil, @body="internal error: put">

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Python implementation below, assuming a filestream input. I was getting the 'internal error: put' as well during the 2nd step, ended up being a malformed request
from io import BytesIO
import requests


SLACK_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxx'
SLACK_ENDPOINT = "https://slack.com/api/"


file_stream = BytesIO()
file_stream.write("Test text.".encode('utf-8'))
filename = 'arg.txt'


file_stream.seek(0, 2)  # Move to end of file
length = file_stream.tell()
file_stream.seek(0)  # Reset to start of file


# Get an upload URL
upload_url_resp = requests.post(
    url=f"{SLACK_ENDPOINT}files.getUploadURLExternal",
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {SLACK_TOKEN}"},
    data={"filename": filename, "length": length}
)
upload_url_data = upload_url_resp.json()
if (upload_url := upload_url_data.get('upload_url')) and (file_id := upload_url_data.get('file_id')):
    # Upload the file to the returned URL
    up_resp = requests.post(
        upload_url,
        files={'file': (filename, file_stream)},
        json={'filename': filename}
    )
  
    resp = requests.post(
        url=f"{SLACK_ENDPOINT}files.completeUploadExternal",
        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {SLACK_TOKEN}"},
        json={
            "files": [{'id': file_id, 'title': filename}],
            "channel_id": 'tgt_channel_id',
            "initial_comment": "Testing File Upload",
        }
    )

